# Append Image to 'parent's sibling's second-child' (2nd cousin) in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following tree:

```
<div>
     <ul>
           <li>
               <span></span>
               <span>HERE</span>
           </li>
           <li>
               <span></span>
               <span>ANOTHERHERE</span>
           </li>
           more li blocks...
     </ul>
     <div>
           <div class="HERE">
           </div>
     </div>
     <div>
           <div class="ANOTHERHERE">
           </div>
     </div>
     more div blocks...
</div>
```

So I am able to select the class="HERE" div (that's where my current JQuery has selected).

How can I select the 'span' which contains the word "HERE" in jquery? (I haven't the logical/experience with JQuery yet).

- The 'class name' will be the same,
- I will also be doing the same with the "ANOTHERHERE" (selecting *its* counterpart in the tree)
- they will be in the same 'order' as one another (first index of li will be corresponding to first index of div, etc)

And then, once I get there, how can i add an image (tag) next to this 'span'.

**attempts**

I was testing with the jquery 'append' method, but i could only ever get the 'text version' to appear, so it looked like:

```
HERE<img src="~/Content/Images/CLOSE.png" />
```

on screen. but instead was looking for

```
HERE X
```

where 'X' is actually the image

I also was playing around with:

```
$(this).parent().next().find('ul').find('li').find('span')
```

but couldn't select the 'correct' span (mind you, I didn't seem to be selecting the span, either :L)

Would anyone have the experience/knowledge of Jquery to explain how to reach/select this element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect selector. `ul` is previous sibling element of selected divs parent div. Use:

```
var currentclass=$(this).attr('class');      
 $(this).parent().prevAll('ul').find('span').filter(function(){
     return $(this).text()==currentclass && $(this).next().length==0; 
}).after('<img src="~/Content/Images/CLOSE.png" /> ');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mzjps7bt/)**

Comment: Thinking that through (slowly, i'm not the best :£), i'm trying to think of a way of making this adaptable for 'ANOTHERHERE'/etc. but it's much better than my attempt, anyway.

Comment: This appends it, but only ever to the first li span. I would *love* it to work on all (and only ever 'append' once).

Comment: Thank you! As you can probably tell, my knowledge of jquery is very limited. So I would like thank you and hope this wasn't too much bother. Cheers again

Comment: Sorry to bother you (again), but is there a way of 'adding' it to that span (not adding it after, as this seems to break my plugin)? i know it's *technically* a different question, but since you've been able to work with this already, you might be able to 'fast track' to the problem?

Comment: use `$(this).parent().prevAll('ul').find('span').filter(function(){
     return $(this).text()==currentclass && $(this).next().length==0; 
}).append('<img src="~/Content/Images/CLOSE.png" /> ');`

Comment: would i be changing the 'if' to this.children, then?

Comment: 'appending' will allow multiple images to be added, and so I thought the $(this).next().length==0 was testing if there was anything *after*, if not 'append'

Comment: got it... use `return $(this).text()==currentclass && $(this).find('img').length==0; `

Answer (score 1):

Simply like this, assuming your in the HERE click function:

```
$(".HERE").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("div").prevAll("ul:first").find("span").filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == "HERE";
    }).append('<img src="~/Content/Images/CLOSE.png" /> ');

});
```

Suppose that the HERE span as also a HERE class `<span class="HERE" ></span>` :

```
$(".HERE").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("div").prevAll("ul:first").find(".HERE").append('<img src="~/Content/Images/CLOSE.png" /> ');

});
```

What is happening in the selector :

1 - closest("div") find the first parent that is a div.

2 - prevAll("ul:first") find all the element on the same level (here ul, first to get the first one)

3 - find(".HERE") find any children with the class HERE

I hope this help